# rtk query typescript interface type issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, rtk-query

I'm attempting to pass a variable to an RTK Query API service that has a typescript interface:

```
const device_id: unique symbol = Symbol(props.id);
const {
    data: device,
    isFetching,
    isLoading,
} = useGetAssetsByIdQuery(device_id, {
    pollingInterval: 3000,
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
    skip: false,
})
```

As you can see I'm taking the `props.id` value (which is passed in as a string) and attempting to convert it to a unique symbol, which is required by the typescript definition of the `useGetAssetsByIdQuery` method.

I'm getting the following error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'unique symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetAssetsByIdApiArg | unique symbol'.
```

I don't understand why, if I'm passing in a `unique symbol` it would still throw the error when the interface clearly specifies *either* `GetAssetsByIdApiArg` or `unique symbol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `unique symbol` is *another* unique symbol, namely the type of the `skipToken` you can pass in there. You have to pass in a `GetAssetsByIdApiArg`.